# Search results not displaying for multiple word search in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, wordpress-theming

I've customized a theme and am having some problems with search results using multiple-word queries. Site is live at [www.abetterworldbydesign.com](http://abetterworldbydesign.com)

[Searching for a single word](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/?s=press) works as expected.

[Searching for multiple words](http://www.abetterworldbydesign.com/?s=press+releases) that should have returned results shows blank results.

Code for searchform.php below.

```
<form id="searchform" name="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'richwp' ); ?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My code in search.php for initializing WP_Query follows exactly [the code listed in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination). Full code for [search.php on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tjGsDePY).

Comment: Also asked on Wordpress Answers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24102/search-results-not-displaying-for-multiple-word-search

Comment: why not to give the search to the powerman - google. Example query "Zero Energy Usage site:www.abetterworldbydesign.com": http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=Zero+Energy+Usage+site:www.abetterworldbydesign.com&pbx=1&oq=Zero+Energy+Usage+site:www.abetterworldbydesign.com&aq=f&aqi=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1400&bih=912

Comment: @Igor - replacing the WordPress search with a Google custom search would be a workaround I'd rather avoid. The main drawback is the requirement to use the Google branding on the site. http://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html

Comment: Nowadays it sounds like: "ok, we rely search on google which guarantees the most reliable results".
How about this, the search phrase is from PDF: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=THE+WINNER+WILL+RECEIVE+A+%241000+STIPEND+TO+PURSUE+THEIR+SOLUTION+AND+site%3Awww.abetterworldbydesign.com&pbx=1&oq=THE+WINNER+WILL+RECEIVE+A+%241000+STIPEND+TO+PURSUE+THEIR+SOLUTION+AND+site:www.abetterworldbydesign.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=26617l26981l2l29179l2l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f7ce9ae2c92611bd&biw=1400&bih=912

Comment: The fact that search "works" when you replace space (`+`) with ampersand (`&`) is not odd at all. When URL is `?s=press+releases`, there is one argument `s` with value `press releases`. When URL is `?s=press&releases`, there are two arguments in URL - one is named `s` with value `press`, another is named `releases` and has empty value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess you need to decode the search term you are extracting from the query string, like so: `$search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1])`. Although, you could probably just use Wordpress's [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) function instead of all that code.

Comment: That was it. Nicely done. Strange that the WordPress documentation doesn't indicate this - wonder if it is a requirement that changed in a recent version of WP and not updated in the documentation. I'd award you the bounty now, but Stack Overflow says I have to wait 3 hours.

Comment: The Wordpress Codex documentation is a wiki so anyone can add to it, and it's best to be a bit sceptical of the content. The code you used was posted by another user over a year ago (you can review the page history if you log in), and I'm not really sure what problem it's supposed to be solving.

Comment: All right. I updated the WordPress Codex with this fix. http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination

Answer (score 0):

Line 16 of your search PHP

```
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
```

Try changing to this

```
$query_args = explode(" ", $query_string)
```

Comment: Tried that. No change. I also tried changing line 16 of search.php to `$query_args = explode("+", $query_string);` but that didn't change anything either

Comment: Weird. I was pretty sure that would work. I'll see if I can see anything else.

Comment: Probably wouldn't do much, but check line 42 of that search.php -- you're comment is commenting out the end of a php tag

Comment: Good catch. I've fixed line 42, but you were right - it didn't do anything.

Comment: As for line 16, I am using code taken directly from the WordPress documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page#Preserving_Search_Page_Results_and_Pagination

Comment: Could you put up your rich.inc.php file?