# How to replace & with + in wordpress search with multiple keyword

Tags: wordpress, search, replace

Hope you are all doing well.

I have created search form with input keyword.

Then when i created the query in word press with **s=>** in word press. The result is showing incorrect if i search with multiple word because of space in between two word convert to &.
so how to replace & to +.

Plz help me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search results not displaying for multiple word search in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819226/search-results-not-displaying-for-multiple-word-search-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a modification in your posted search data and then process it further. Have a look at this hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_query/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).